# customise RSS feeds

Tags: php, joomla, rss

I need some help regarding RSS feeds. I need all the RSS feeds data from multiple website should arrive on Joomla Administer panel first, then administrator select feeds from them and publish to main page. I need same functionality for Forum also. Is there any extension which provides same functionality or what will be approach to it?

Regards

Comment: @iWantSimpleLife nothing upto now... i am just reviewing over internet. i even dn't know how RSS  work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an extension from the [Joomla! Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/) that will probably meet your needs for RSS import, try looking at the [Automatic Articles section](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-edition/automatic-articles).

We've used this - [ObFullTextRSS](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-edition/automatic-articles/11403)-  one for several clients but I'm not sure about the Admin approval side of things.

Comment: if it doesnt support then what will be the solution for this?